# How do I get the name of the Object Identifier in Gson/Json?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a Json file like this

```
{Users:[{
user1 :{
email: "sth"
phone : "sth"
}},
user2:{
email:"sth"
phone:"sth"
}]}
```

The above is an read only file. I am using the following code :

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    Myclass myclass= gson.fromJson(br, Myclass.class);
```

So I can get the values of email and phone using my class. but I want the username also.
i.e. user1 email phone
user2 email phone

Answer (score 0):

Have the username as another property, as in:

```
{Users:[{ name: "user1", email: "sth", phone : "sth" }, {name: "user2", email:"sth", phone:"sth"}]}
```

To give more detail it would help if you could show us Myclass, but it should look something like this:

```
public class Myclass [

    private List<User> Users;

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return Users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> Users) {
        this.Users = Users;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class User {

    private String email;

    private String name;

    private String phone;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

This would work with your code.

Comment: Thanks fo rthe answer but as I said, I cannot modify the json file. I had thought of this solution but I am not allowed to modify the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't modify the json then you may have to write your own deserializer. Something like this:

```
public class UserDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<User> {

    @Override
    public User deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) {
        Map.Entry<String, User> userAndName = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().entrySet().iterator().next();

        String name = userAndName.getKey();

        JsonObject userInfo = userAndName.getValue().getAsJsonObject();

        String email = userInfo.get("email").getAsString();
        String phone = userInfo.get("phone").getAsString();

        return new User(name, email, phone);
    }
}
```

You would then register the deserializer when creating your gson instance:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(User.class, new UserDeserializer())
    .create();
```